# Android released app has no internet access Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, permissions, release

Recently Xamarin "became" Visual Studio for Mac and since then I can't release my app with internet permission. In my AndroidManifest file there are all needed permissions, but my app still can't use internet.

I tried all possible linker configuration in case some files are being omitted during release but still no effect. Of course it works fine in debug mode, it seems like Visual Studio does not take into account my AndroidManifest file in Release mode.

I've checked the file at it's directory path and it looks fine - it contains all needed permissions.

Did anyone experience this before? Should I upgrade everything what is possible and pray for effect?

Here is file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    package="xx" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
        <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="26" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_GSERVICES" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
        <application android:label="4Panel" android:icon="@drawable/smallLogo" android:largeHeap="true" android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme">
            <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="xxxx" />
            <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="4030500" />
        </application>
    </manifest>
```

Mono  ver. 5.10.1.47
Android 8.0

@Update

AndroidManifest obj/Release/android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="xxx" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="26" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_GSERVICES" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network" />
  <application android:label="4Panel" android:icon="@drawable/smalllogo" android:largeHeap="true" android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme" android:name="md59eb01b0d32d644592fe52f1772bd748a.MainApplication" android:allowBackup="true">
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="xxx" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="4030500" />
    <activity android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" android:icon="@drawable/smalllogo" android:label="4Panel" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnspecified|adjustPan" android:name="md59eb01b0d32d644592fe52f1772bd748a.MainActivity" />
    <activity android:label="4Panel" android:name="md59eb01b0d32d644592fe52f1772bd748a.Login">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" android:icon="@drawable/smalllogo" android:label="Szczegóły zadania" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnspecified|adjustPan" android:name="md59eb01b0d32d644592fe52f1772bd748a.QuestDetails" />
    <activity android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" android:icon="@drawable/smalllogo" android:label="Szczegóły zadania" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnspecified|adjustPan" android:name="md59eb01b0d32d644592fe52f1772bd748a.ArchiveDetailsQ" />
    <provider android:name="mono.MonoRuntimeProvider" android:exported="false" android:initOrder="2147483647" android:authorities="x4Panel.x4Lan.mono.MonoRuntimeProvider.__mono_init__" />
    <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" android:exported="false" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
  </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Look at the final AndroidManifest.xml that gets bundled in the apk (in the Release/obj dir)

Comment: Thanks for reply, I posted AndroidManifest.xml content from obj/Release/android/ as question update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically solution is to create new project in VS and copy there every single class, etc. For some reason VS does not include AndroidManifest content created in Xamarin.